# Having trouble installing python-pip; is this on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the following question on-topic? If not, would it be better suited to Super User, or maybe to Unix & Linux?

> I'm attempting to install python-pip without root access using `python get-pip.py --user`, but I keep getting a `ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname` error.
>
> #### Some background info
>
> I just installed python 2.7.9 (without root access) as follows:
>
> ```
> ~ % wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz
> ~ % ./configure --prefix=/export/users/steinea/python-2.7.9
> ~ % make install
> ```
>
> I then prepended the new pythonpath to `$path` by adding the following to the bottom of `~/.cshrc` (my department uses C Shell instead of bash):
>
> ```
> set pythonpath=/export/users/steinea/python-2.7.9/bin
> set path=($pythonpath $path)
> ```
>
> I downloaded `get-pip.py` from the https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html page.

Comment: Looks on topic for SO to me... (although I'm sure there's lots of questions regarding difficulties installing pip)

Comment: [Here's an example of one.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28296476/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto That question actually answered mine! So, it turns out I no longer have a need to post this. Thanks!

Comment: @AviSteiner Let this be a lesson to you to search before you post a new question.  It might save everyone's time.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I always search, but I don't always know enough about the topic to know _what_ to search for.

Answer (score 1):

> Having trouble installing python-pip; is this on-topic?

I'll take a stab at providing an opinion.

```
~ % wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz
```

Wget fetch is not on-topic. It is just another question on how to use the Wget command. I assume it is not relevant to the problem since you moved on to the next step.

```
~ % ./configure --prefix=/export/users/steinea/python-2.7.9
~ % make
~ % make install
```

Here, you are ***building*** software from sources. You are not ***installing*** software *per se*. Building software from sources is on-topic at Stack Overflow. You are wielding the programming tools used by developers for the purpose of development. It is the reason Stack Overflow exists.

```
set pythonpath=/export/users/steinea/python-2.7.9/bin
set path=($pythonpath $path)
```

Back to off-topic stuff. It is just another question on how to configure your shell.

Now we don't know where you are having trouble. If the problem is with Wget or shell configuration, then I'd say it is off-topic and should be asked at another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites). If the problem is with `configure`, `make`, or `make install`, then it is on-topic at Stack Overflow.

Keep in mind if your configure or compile command fails you still have to provide relevant context. Dumping the error or say, a stack trace in the case of `pip install`, is not enough. We still need to see the command line and the relevant code. If you don't provide the context then the question could be closed for other reasons. The close reason would likely be the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

Now, suppose you successfully built and installed Pip. Should a `pip install <favorite package>` question be on-topic? I think it depends but I think the answer is usually NO.

Pip is written in Python and a question usually (should?) include a stack trace. But it is just an packager manager error, like an error from Yum or Apt. In this case there is no material difference from a Python backtrace and a Yum or Apt error.

The Pip backtrace could be made on-topic by going to the source and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But that does not happen because the questions are germane package manager errors, and not programming specific questions.

---

This combination is kind of interesting because we generally don't see it:

```
~ % ./configure --prefix=/export/users/steinea/python-2.7.9
...
set pythonpath=/export/users/steinea/python-2.7.9/bin
set path=($pythonpath $path)
```

Here, you are gluing the build together with something else. I would *not* move against it given the context. But if you omit the build steps then I think you fall back into off-topic.

---

In general someone who is tasked with a job has to break it into subtasks. Some of the subtasks will be on-topic here, and some of the subtasks will be off-topic here. Sites in the Stack Exchange network are not one-size fits all.

Please don't accept this (or other answers) as they are merely opinions. The exception to the rule is an answer with 2500 or so upvotes. At 2500 or so upvotes you can say consensus has been reached.

Comment: So, every user of gentoo is a software developer then, because gentoo by default builds everything by default. That isn't a good strategy to attract SO group target: enthusiasts and professional software developers. Unless you are developing the software you are trying to build, building by itself isn't on topic.

Comment: @Braiam - If a Gentoo user's problem is encountered at the build stage, then yes. But the onus is on the user to provide the necessary context. If they dump a compile error without context then the question will likely be closed for another reason.

Comment: Seems that I was opaque enough that my point was lost. The thing is that the Gentoo users would know nothing about the specific piece of code that it is failing during build. A good SO question requires that you at least know what the correct/desired behavior is before even attempting to solve the problem. If we don't know why someValue is a char instead of an int and what SomeFunction supposed to do with it, there would be no way we can accurately pinpoint where the problem lies.